# Codeigniter controller error warnings. undefined function db item and declarations compatible

Tags: php, codeigniter, server, hosting

Im working on a script that i download online but when i install codeigniter it brings this.

```
 Severity: Warning

Message: Declaration of MY_Lang::line($line = '') should be compatible with CI_Lang::line($line, $log_errors = true)

Filename: core/MY_Lang.php

Line Number: 41
```

And here's my Controller

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang {

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Load a language file
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   mixed   the name of the language file to be loaded. Can be an array
     * @param   string  the language (english, etc.)
     * @param   bool    return loaded array of translations
     * @param   bool    add suffix to $langfile
     * @param   string  alternative path to look for language file
     * @return  mixed
     */
    function load($langfile = '', $idiom = '', $return = FALSE, $add_suffix = TRUE, $log_errors = TRUE, $alt_path = '', $line ='')
    {       
        parent::load($langfile, $idiom, $return, $add_suffix, $alt_path, $log_errors, $line);
    }

    function get_array()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }

    function line($line = '')
    {
        $value = ($line == '' OR ! isset($this->language[$line])) ? FALSE : $this->language[$line];

        // Because killer robots like unicorns!
        if ($value === FALSE)
        {
            log_message('debug', 'Could not find the language line "'.$line.'"');
        }

        return $value;
    }

}
```

i don't know where is wrong, i already brake a little of fatal error warnings, but this one has my dry.

On the other hand, a second mistake that bounces me is this

```
Message: Call to undefined function config_db_item()

Filename: /home/casabla6/public_html/application/core/MY_Loader.php
```

and in the controller i have this.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
{
   function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();

      $this->_ci_view_paths += array(FCPATH.'templates/'=>TRUE);
   }

    public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        $admin_template = '';
        if( config_db_item ('admin_template') !== FALSE)
            $admin_template = config_db_item('admin_template');


        if(strpos($view, 'admin/') === 0)
            $view = $admin_template.'/'.$view;

        if(isset($vars['subview']))
        {
            if(strpos($vars['subview'], 'admin/') === 0)
                $vars['subview'] = $admin_template.'/'.$vars['subview'];
        }

        return parent::view($view, $vars, $return);
    }

    function common_view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        $view = 'common/'.$view;

        return parent::view($view, $vars, $return);
    }

}

?>
```

can u give me a hand please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class `MY_Lang` extends `CI_Lang`, which means the method `MY_Lang::line()` should have a definition that matches the method `CI_Lang::line()`.

The original method in `CI_Lang`:

```
public function line($line, $log_errors = true)
```

Your extension in `MY_Lang`:

```
public function line($line = '')
```

You'll need to change your code to take the same arguments:

```
public function line($line, $log_errors = true)
```

Comment: i have a little of what u says, can u please help me a bit more?

Comment: where and what i must change?

Comment: When you extend a class that already has a function it has to have the same number and type of arguments. Read "You'll need to change your code to take the same arguments:"... you need to include `$log_errors` in your function arguments (but you don't need to use it in the function)

Comment: thanks! a lot! it works, about the second did u know something?
Message: Call to undefined function config_db_item()

Comment: You're trying to call a function that doesn't exist. Either `config_db_item()` is not defined anywhere, or you haven't included the source file that defines it.